Django Rest Framework Many To Many serializer problem
I'm creating an API in Django Rest Framework and I have a problem with a ManyToMany relation.
I'm trying to create an movie and assign genre to it (ManyToMany relationship between movie and genre).
Here are my models:
class Genre(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False,max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,null=False,blank=False)
    adult = models.BooleanField(null=False,blank=False)
    backdrop_path = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=200)
    budget = models.BigIntegerField (default=0)
    homepage = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=200)
    original_language = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    original_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    overview = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    poster_path = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=200)
    release_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True,)
    revenue = models.BigIntegerField (default=0)
    runtime = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tagline = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre,blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

here are my serializers:
class GenresSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ['id','name']
        
    def create(self,validated_data):
        
        instance, _ = Genre.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
        return instance
    
class MovieGenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ['id']
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance, _ = Genre.objects.get(**validated_data)
        return instance
    
class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genres = GenresSerializers(many= True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = [ 'id', 'adult', 'backdrop_path', 'budget', 'homepage', 'original_language', 'original_title', 'overview', 'poster_path', 'release_date', 'revenue', 'runtime', 'status', 'tagline', 'title', 'genres'
            ]
        # extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only': True}}
        
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        genres_data = validated_data.pop('genres', []) 
        
        genresInstances = []
        for genre in genres_data:
            genresInstances.append(Genre.objects.get(pk = genre['id']))
        movie = Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)
        movie.genre.set(genresInstances)
        return movie

and my viewsets:
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MoviesSerializer

When I try to create a new movie with this request body (I already have created genres):
{
  "id": 425,
  "adult": false,
  "backdrop_path": "/kK5OeulwVDniPgjNOGHvzcORzdG.jpg",
  "budget": 59000000,
  "homepage": "http://www.iceagemovies.com/films/ice-age",
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_title": "Ice Age",
  "overview": "With the impending ice age almost upon them, a mismatched trio of prehistoric critters – Manny the woolly mammoth, Diego the saber-toothed tiger and Sid the giant sloth – find an orphaned infant and decide to return it to its human parents. Along the way, the unlikely allies become friends but, when enemies attack, their quest takes on far nobler aims.",
  "poster_path": "/stQoHvo0q6ZcEkji2Z1wlAxKnDq.jpg",
  "release_date": "2002-03-10",
  "revenue": 383257136,
  "runtime": 81,
  "status": "Released",
  "tagline": "They came. They thawed. They conquered.",
  "title": "Ice Age",
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 16
    },
    {
      "id": 35
    },
    {
      "id": 10751
    },
    {
      "id": 12
    }

  ]
}

it return like this:
{
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": [
        "genre with this id already exists."
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": [
        "genre with this id already exists."
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": [
        "genre with this id already exists."
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": [
        "genre with this id already exists."
      ]
    }
  ]
}

EDIT:
edit in admin site
i have edit in admin site, add, delete genre to exist movie and save but it not save and the database not change

Well it tries to create Genres because of the subserializer.

Don't use a subserializer, use for example a SlugRelatedFieldSerializer [drf-doc]:
class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genres = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Genre.objects.all(), slug_field='name'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = [
            'id',
            'adult',
            'backdrop_path',
            'budget',
            'homepage',
            'original_language',
            'original_title',
            'overview',
            'poster_path',
            'release_date',
            'revenue',
            'runtime',
            'status',
            'tagline',
            'title',
            'genres',
        ]
        # extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only': True}}

    # no create
You create the items then with:
{
    # …,
    "genres": ["horror", "music", "musical"]
}

i have tried your solution but the genres is blank:
{
"id": 425,
"adult": false,
...
"genres": []
}

@12341413451354134: blank for what? Reading/writing?

in the api response, genres blank when i post, it not update in database

@12341413451354134: you did remove the def create method?

yes, i removed create

i have tried delete movie_genres table in database and create again and it work, before code i have import csv to table, it can be a reason?

@12341413451354134: I would think not, but it is of course hard to say with only a Serializer and ViewSet, etc. But it works now?

There are performance issues in the MoviesSerializer as you are calling Genre.objects.get(pk = genre['id']) in for loop. It will call the database multiple times.
Since, you have already created the genre. Try this Serializer:
class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genres = serializers.ListField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = [ 'id', 'adult', 'backdrop_path', 'budget', 'homepage', 'original_language', 'original_title', 'overview', 'poster_path', 'release_date', 'revenue', 'runtime', 'status', 'tagline', 'title', 'genres'
            ]
        # extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only': True}}
        
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        genres_data = validated_data.pop('genres', []) 
        
        genresIds = [g["id"] for g in genres_data]
        genresInstances = Genre.objects.filter(id__in=genresIds)

        movie = Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)
        movie.genres.set(genresInstances)
        return movie

